# On Change JS not working within PHP string

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the same code in two places. If I have this in a standard  tag section of my page it runs flawlessly. However when I move the onchange input field to a script, more specifically a while loop which echos content within a '', it fails to work.

```
First Name: <input id="first_name" name="first_name" onchange="ajax_post();" type="text">  <br><br>
```

Any ideas anybody?

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? Are there any console errors? Why is this tagged as PHP?

Comment: Use your developer console to look for JS errors.  Rendering this in PHP should have no effect on the Javascript.

Comment: Could you give us the while loop code?  Though, if the onchange is in the while loop, you should try moving it out of the while loop.

Comment: I have a div with an id of status. When the on change command is fired it updates said div with the content based on the first name. This isnt showing anything. JS works as have tried in other parts of page but doesnt seem to work within this loop.

Comment: could it be that you have multiple inputs with the same id?

Answer (score 0):

Your onchange function syntax is wrong , the original is "onChange" . I think it will work now .